# How to solve HTTP Error 429 in BioPython?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, http-status-code-429

I'm trying to use BioPython to acquire nucleotide sequences by inputting accession number and start and end positions. I need to acquire many sequences but the process was aborted just after 3 sequences. I got this error:
"urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests". 
Could it be that I used BioPython to run blast too many times previously? It took about three weeks to finish the alignments for my last task. Does it mean I have been blocked by the server?

Comment: Did you have a look at the request limit here? https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25497/

Comment: Oh, I see. I once did it a year ago and they added this rule after that. Thank you.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters Biopython should handle this itself, if you upgrade to Biopython 1.73, here is the relevant pull request https://github.com/biopython/biopython/pull/1869

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [this post](https://ncbiinsights.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/2017/11/02/new-api-keys-for-the-e-utilities/) about the use of API keys with NCBI e-utilities and add the API key to your scripts to avoid this error.

Comment: Problem solved, I add the api_key and sleep time in the loop. Thank you.

Comment: If any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.